(Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
I have been trying for too long. Still getting error at browser even though my nginx proxy has CORS defined.
Im using Cloudflare. I have A record which is called api.company.com (Proxied DNS). When user sends request to this url, the routing at nginx reverse proxy able to route to my localhost api that running on the server of the URL. But after 30 seconds while the api still processing the request, getting the CORS error. I have configured my api to accept * origin. Here is my nginx config:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.company.com;

    location / {
        # Handle preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Range, Authorization' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;  # Cache preflight response for 20 days
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;
            return 204;  # No content
        }

        # Proxy settings for other methods
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Timeout settings
        proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
        proxy_send_timeout 90s;
        proxy_read_timeout 90s;
        send_timeout 90s;
    }
}


UI React Query Codes:

export const quality_control = (body) =>
    qc_api.post("/quality_control", body).then((e) => {
        return e.data;
    });
const useQualityCheck = () => {
 
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: quality_control,
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            if (data.success === true) {
                console.log("success response", data.message);
            } else {
                console.log("error response", data.message);
            }
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log("error response", error);
            }
        },
 
    });
};

2 There is no codes to handle the Cross origin from client side app. Browser sends the request to my server and my NGINX reverse proxy will handle request based on whether UI access or api access. This is my UI NGINX condfig:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ui.company.com;

    # Forward requests to the React app running on port 8080
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;  # React app running on port 8080
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

3 This is my fastapi backend codes running at localhost:8000
app = FastAPI(
    **fastapi_kwargs,
    swagger_ui_parameters={"defaultModelsExpandDepth": -1},
    middleware=[
        Middleware(
                CORSMiddleware,                                                        allow_headers=["*"],
            allow_credentials=True,
            allow_origins=["*"],
            allow_methods=["*"],
        ),
    ],).

My api function to handle the request from nginx proxy:
def check_quality_control(
    request: Request,
    payload: CheckQualityControlRequestModel = Depends(
        CheckQualityControlRequestModel.as_multipart_form
    ),
) -> CheckQualityControlResponseModel:
    result = llava_next.evaluate_image(
        car_image=payload.image,
        model=request.app.state.model,
        processor=request.app.state.processor,
    )

    # Remove unwanted data
    data_to_remove = ["image", "prompt", "output"]
    result = {key: value for key, value in result.items() if key not in data_to_remove}

    formatted_feedback = {}
    for key, value in result.items():
        for _, text in value.items():
            # Extract the score from the text
            score_index = text.rfind("Score:")
            score = text[score_index + len("Score:") :].strip()
            feedback_text = text[:score_index].strip()

            # Format the result
            formatted_feedback[key] = {
                "Feedback": feedback_text,
                "Score": score,
            }
    return CheckQualityControlResponseModel(**formatted_feedback)

My browser response while API still processing:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.company.comi/quality_control. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)


What are the actual headers returned by the request? Is the request timing out?

Where I can fetch the headers details? @MatsLindh

You'd see those in your browser's network tools. If no response is returned (for example because of a timeout), there are no headers to read. Open up the browser's developer tools, select the network tab and look at what is actually being returned from the server - or if the request times out.
